# Как сделать скроллящийся выбор элементов в unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Как сделать такой выбор в unity на андроид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думал создать панель и на неё навесить скролл с выбором элементов, но данный вариант не подойдёт так как будет слишком много вариантов.

Comment: Как самый простой вариант - сделайте 9 фиксированных меток (как на картинке), на input подавайте текущее число, которое будет являться опорным, относительно этого числа, делайте 4 числа вниз, 4 числа вверх. Например. Подаёте 10. В центральную метку выводите это число, в остальные делаете 10+1, 10+2, 10+3, 10+4, и в другую сторону 10-1, 10-2, 10-3, 10-4. И заполняйте соответствующие метки. Будет иллюзия прокрутки. Пальцем пользователь будет менять только 1 число input.

Comment: Для полноценной прокрутки колесом с анимацией - можно использовать аналогичный подход, но, придётся добавить математики, для позиционирования меток. Опять же, для анимации можно использовать 9 меток, при уходе метки за зону видимости (например, угол по оси >=90 градусов в ейлеровой системе координат), перемещаете её на место метки, которая вот вот должна появится с другого края.

Comment: Хорошо,первая идея мне нравится, а как с помощью скроллинга менять значение int?

Comment: У Canvas объектов есть события Drag-Drop, в них можете отловить направление движения пальца (вас будет интерисовать движение по вертикали), и по нему прибавлять какую нибудь константу к текущему числу.

Comment: Смотрите IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler